# How can l compare tx fee for main network and testnet

Tags: blockchain, gas-price, fees

I have a contract on testnet and how can l learn how much tx fee will be on main network with same contract. Is there any way to get this information.

Comment: If the contract are exactly the same then gas used should be equal. Obviously gas prices are cannot be compared. If the contract interact with other contract the estimates could vary a lot.